# Select A Specific Class In An Each Statement

Tags: jquery

I the following code returns every text that has the "price" class associated to it. I just want to return the price of the specific item the each statement is on..

```
<div class="item">
    <p class="price">$388.00</p>
    <p class="part_number">VM2327T23A00T</p>
    <p class="real_price"></p>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <p class="price">$88.00</p>
    <p class="part_number">AA327T23A00T</p>
    <p class="real_price"></p>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <p class="price">$38.00</p>
    <p class="part_number">AA327T23A00T</p>
    <p class="real_price"></p>
</div>

<script>
jQuery('.part_number').each(function () {
    parts.push(jQuery(this).text());
    var aPrice= jQuery('.price').text();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
jQuery('.part_number').each(function () {
    parts.push(jQuery(this).text());
    var aPrice= jQuery(this).siblings('.price').text();
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Well,i suppose you should code the HTML as.Since all the three items have "item" ans "price" class associated to them.

```
<div class="item" class="price">
   <p>$388.00</p>
     <p class="part_number">VM2327T23A00T</p>
     <p class="real_price"></p>
  <p>$88.00</p>
     <p class="part_number">AA327T23A00T</p>
     <p class="real_price"></p>
  <p>$38.00</p>
     <p class="part_number">AA327T23A00T</p>
     <p class="real_price"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: How would this help get the associated price?